# Send object filter to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, filtering

I currently access a Web API endpoint serving up hierarchical objects (complex deals) using JSON/BSON. The objects are translated from entity framework objects stored as standard normalised data in a SQL Server database. This all works well.

However, as the number of these objects grows it becomes increasingly inefficient to serialise/deserialise them across the wire before filtering out those required at the client. Having methods for all objects or object-by-id is fine, but often there are more complex criteria for filtering which would require a myriad of different method signatures to fully capture. In an ideal world it would be possible to send `Func<Deal,bool>` to the Deals endpoint and this would provide the filtering mechanism from the client side to be enacted server-side. The premise being that different users will be interested in deals based on varying facets.

This may be mad, but is there any way that something along these lines can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I do this by passing a "SearchCriteria" object to the search endpoint and then performing filtering at the server based on the values set in the various criteria properties. However, we do have a fairly well defined list of criteria and performing the filtering isn't too bad.

Alternatively, I've not used OData, but from what I understand this might be what you are looking for. If I was pondering this again I would investigate this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint